# Update TextBox Value on Blur Event in Asp.Net MVC5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have employees particulars in tabular form. I want to update the cell number of the employees so that I populate that number in TextBox in Table Cell .. how can I save that number to datatbase when onblur event fire...

```
$("#Mobile").blur(function UpdateEmployeeMobile() {
var MobileNo = $("#Mobile").val();    
var EMPLOYEEID = $("#StudentID").val();    
var ID = EMPLOYEEID + "-" + MobileNo;    
$.post("/Employee/UpdateMobile/" + ID, null, function (data) {    
});    
});
```

Comment: Show your HTML where you want to populate?

Comment: <td><input class="hidden" id="EMPLOYEEID" name="EMPLOYEEID" type="text" value="@item.ID"  />
<input id="Mobile" name="Mobile" type="text" value="@item.Mobile" />
@Satpal

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#Mobile").blur(function() {
  var MobileNo = $(this).val();    
  var EMPLOYEEID = $("#StudentID").val();    
  var ID = EMPLOYEEID + "-" + MobileNo;    
  $.post("/Employee/UpdateMobile/" + ID, status, function (data) {  
     ...  
  });    
});
```